# In Visual Studio App Center, how can I filter by Build number on the Issues page?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-app-center, visual-studio-app-center-build

I have an Android app developed in Xamarin.Forms. It's using Visual Studio App Center to build the APK, track issues and distribute to the app stores.

I want to track which issues are associated with a particular build.

On the Diagnostics > Issues page in Visual Studio App Center, there's a dropdown for Build. However the option is gryed out and I cannot filter by Build number.

[image]

How can I filter by Build on the issues page?

Comment: I believe this means that there is only one build in the dataset for the selected period.  If you change the Time filter to 90 days does the Build filter become active?

Comment: @Jason There should have been 4 builds in the last 90 days, however setting the timescale to 90 days does not unlock the dropdown.

Comment: You need first select version number, and after that build filter will be populated.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT that fixed my issue.

Comment: I added an answer there and can you please mark it so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need first select version number, and after that build filter will be populated.